# video to Window.sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, canvas, video, buffer, session-store

I made a github-page with a little animation on canvas and scroll, by loading a really small (600KB on the webm version and 2MB on the mp4 version) loop video and re-painting second by second 
on scroll event.

It works perfectly but I've noticed that some times the animation gets stuck in a frame or the animation gets slower and not fluid and looks like the browser 
seeks for the data on-line because the cache max-age each 10 minutes.

How can I sessionstore my video.currentsrc in the browser to have it on hand for canvas??

Or is there another better way you can suggest me?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("video");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var fish = document.getElementById("fish");
fish.load();

var lastScrollTop = 0;
var fwo = 0,
  fho = 0,
  fw, fh, ft = 0;

function fishSetup() {
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  fw = (canvas.height * fish.videoWidth) / fish.videoHeight;
}
fish.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
  fishSetup();
  render(fish);
  $(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
      //console.log('prev');
      ft -= 1;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
      //console.log('next');
      ft += 1;
    }
    if (ft >= fish.duration) {
      ft = 0;
    } else if (ft <= 0) {
      ft = fish.duration;
    }
    fish.currentTime = ft;
  });
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      //console.log("down")
      ft += 1;
    } else {
      //console.log("up")
      ft -= 1;
    }
    if (ft >= fish.duration) {
      ft = 0;
    } else if (ft <= 0) {
      ft = fish.duration;
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
    fish.currentTime = ft;
  });
}, false);


fish.onseeked = function() {
  render(fish);
};

function render(video) {
  ctx.drawImage(video, fwo, fho, fw, canvas.height);
}
```

```css
video {
  display: none;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100000000000000000px;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <video id="fish" style="display: fixed !important;" muted crossorigin>
  <source src="https://mauriciovillegasbelmont.github.io/portafolio/assets/vid/fish-30s_1fps_30q_5kf.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="https://mauriciovillegasbelmont.github.io/portafolio/assets/vid/fish-30s_1fps_0-5mbr_5kf.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  <canvas id="video">
        your browser dosn´t soppourt canvas
</canvas>
</section>
```

Comment: So you don't really need to be in memory for more than the document's life? Then downloading it as a Blob and using a blobURI should be enough. Note that it will take longer at init time though, since the whole file would have to be completely downloaded. And if you want to store it for longer terms, then use the IndexedDb API. Storage API is really not meant for b8nary data. It is slow and synchronous, and limited...

Comment: thanks man; i'll try with the IndexedDb and i have it present